# How to use Perl's File::Grep module

Tags: perl

I am using the [`File::Grep`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Grep) module. I have following example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Grep qw( fgrep fmap fdo );

my @matches = fgrep { 1.1.1 } glob "file.csv";

foreach my $str (@matches) {
    print "$str\n";
}
```

But when I try to print `$str` value it gives me `HEX` value: `GLOB(0xac2e78)`

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@matches;` will tell you what the returned data looks like

Comment: `$VAR1 = [
          {
            'filename' => 'file.csv',
            'count' => 11,
            'matches' => {
                           '14' => '1.1.1,some text ges here'
             }
          }
        ];`

Comment: something like this I am getting match after adding use `Data::Dumper;` `print Dumper \@matches;`.

Comment: But its still not printing value in loop.

Comment: `1.1.1` is an odd thing to match on. That's a version literal, equivalent to the string `"\x1\x1\x1" -- and  you're not comparing anything to it. And I wonder why you're using `glob` on a string with no wildcard characters.

Comment: In [the modulel](https://metacpan.org/source/MNEYLON/File-Grep-0.02 "File::Grep") I found no tests for fdo and the module was last touched in 2005. So my advice is to be careful with this module.

Comment: @Keith Thompson. Just started learning perl. This is mine 2nd program which I am trying to do. Maybe I will do mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation doesn't seem to be accurate, but judging from the source-code — http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MNEYLON/File-Grep-0.02/Grep.pm — the list you get back from `fgrep` contains one element per file. Each element is a hash of the form

```
{
    filename => $filename,
    count => $num_matches_in_that_file,
    matches => {
        $line_number => $line,
        ...
    }
}
```

I think it would be simpler to skip `fgrep` and its complicated return-value that has way more information than you want, in favor of `fdo`, which lets you just iterate over all lines of a file and do what you want:

```
 fdo { my ( $file, $pos, $line ) = @_;
       print $line if $line =~ m/1\.1\.1/;
 } 'file.csv';
```

(Note that I removed the `glob`, by the way. There's not much point in writing `glob "file.csv"`, since only one file can match that globstring.)

or even just dispense with this module and write:

```
{
     open my $fh, '<', 'file.csv';
     while (<$fh>) {
         print if m/1\.1\.1/;
     }
}
```

Comment: There's no point in retaining the OP's filter block `{ 1.1.1 }` as it will just select all lines from every file.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to see all the lines in `file.csv` that contain `1.1.1`?

The documentation for `File::Grep` isn't up to date, but this program will put into `@lines` all the matching lines from all the files (if there were more than one).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Grep qw/ fgrep /;
$File::Grep::SILENT = 0;

my @matches = fgrep { /1\.1\.1/ } 'file.csv';

my @lines = map {
  my $matches = $_->{matches};
  @{$matches}{ sort { $a <=> $b } keys %$matches};
} @matches;

print for @lines;
```

---

**Update**

The most Perlish way to do this is like so

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'file.csv' or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
  print if /1\.1\.1/;
}
```

Comment: Finally, I fount that in perl there are many ways to achieve same answer, confused which one to use.

Comment: @snoop: I have added to my answer to explain how to use a simple read loop to achieve the same end.

Comment: But in your updated case we are iterating through while loop, its quite time consuming instead of just grep-ing the text from file. Which will be better looping through data or just grep it from file?

Comment: @snoop: The file has to be read all the way through, whether it's hidden inside `fgrep` or exposed as an explicit `while` loop. If this produces the result you need then use it -- it's likely to be marginally *faster* than `fgrep` because it is simpler.